# Is there an exit in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use php and there is a handy exit; that will stop the execution of the page and let me view the page thus far and then lets me view the debugging that i need ..anything like that in ruby on rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do raise an exception in your code which stops the current method and prints the exception. Great for debugging.

For example `raise @variable.inspect`. Also calling the inspect method will show you a lot of information about your variable. Also you can use this in your views controllers models helpers if you are using rails.

In your view:

```
<%= raise @variable.inspect%>
```

Answer (score 5):

The best method for debugging in rails is to start your server with debugging enabled `ruby script/server --debugger` (this requires the ruby-debug gem) `gem install ruby-debug`

You can then put `<% debugger %>` in your views, controllers or wherever you like (obviously omit the erb tags if outside of a view). the terminal you have the server running in will then show you a breakpoint debugger `help` from the prompt there will tell you more.

Answer (score 2):

A direct mapping to PHP's exit function would be [Kernel::exit()](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005930) (or simply exit())

Specifically in a Rails view: `<%= debug @whatever %>`. [More Info](http://jeremyhubert.com/articles/debugging-in-rails.html)